# Capybara poltergeist timeout error after upgrading to OS X 10.9.3

Tags: capybara, phantomjs, osx-mavericks, poltergeist

I have UI test on capybara, which includes this line:

```
page.click_link("Current users")
```

After I updated MacOS X from 10.9.2 to 10.9.3 I observed the following error during test running:

> Failure/Error: @user.approve_user
>        Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:
>          Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"click","args":[8,0]}. It's possible that this happened
>   because something took a very long time (for example a page load was
>   slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher
>   value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout
>   does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report
>   it to the issue tracker.

- ruby 2.0.0p481
- Rails 3.2.18
- phantomjs 1.9.7
- gem 'capybara', '2.2.1'
- gem 'poltergeist', '1.5.0'

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.5.1 of poltergeist fixed it for me (but before it did, I'd also recompiled phantomjs).

```
$ bundle update poltergeist
```

Comment: @Graham Ashton: Did you recompile the same version, or build a new version?